# Provision a GCP VM instance with Static IP via Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, terraform, hashicorp-vault, google-provisioning-api

I have edited my main.tf and variable.tf file as suggested by @**Claire Bellivier** but still getting the same error, please have a look.
**Main.tf:**

```
# Path to the authentification to GCP json file
provider "google" {
 credentials = "${file("${var.path_gcp_auth_json_file}")}"
 version     = "~> 2.2"

}

resource =  "google_compute_address" "test-static-ip-address" {
 count  = "${var.gcp_ip_count}"
 name   = "${var.gcp_project_id}-gke-ip-${count.index}"
 region = "${var.region}"
 }

resource "google_compute_instance" "tests" {
 name         = "project-tests"
 project      = "xyz"
 machine_type = "f1-micro"
 zone         = "us-west1-a"

 tags = ["gcp"]

 boot_disk {
 initialize_params {
  image = "ubuntu-os-cloud/ubuntu-1804-lts"
   }
 }

network_interface {
 network = "default"

  access_config {
   nat_ip = "${google_compute_address.test-static-ip-address.address}"

   }
 }

  metadata {
   sshKeys = "local:${file(var.ssh_public_key_filepath)}"
  }

}

resource "google_compute_firewall" "firewalls" {
 name    = "firewalls"
 project = "video-library-228319"
 network = "default"

 allow {
  protocol = "tcp"
  ports = ["80", "443"]
 }

  source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}
```

**Variable.tf**

```
# Path to the authentification to GCP json file
variable "path_gcp_auth_json_file" {
  description = "Path to the authentication JSON file"
 default = "account.json"
}


variable "ssh_public_key_filepath" {
 description = "Filepath to local ssh public key"
 type = "string"

 default = "local.pub"
}

variable "gcp_ip_count" {
 default = "1"
}

variable "gcp_project_id" {
  default = "xyz"
}

variable "region" {
 default ="us-west1-a"
}
```

**Error: Unknown root level key: test-static-ip-address
Error: resource 'google_compute_instance.tests' config: unknown resource 'google_compute_address.test-static-ip-address' referenced in variable google_compute_address.test-static-ip-address.address**

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you copy paste this one and delete the second block?

```
resource "google_compute_address" "test-static-ip-address" {
  count  = "${var.gcp_ip_count}"
  name   = "${var.gcp_project_id}-gke-ip-${count.index}"
  region = "${var.region}"
}
```

As mentioned there is a `=` too many, so it cannot work.

The pattern is always for the `main.tf` file:

```
resource "<kind of GCP Resource>" "<the name of your resources> {
  <list of arguments you need>
  # ...
}
```

A little trick if you need help with the Terraform syntax, you can proceed some tests with those commands: `terraform format` to get the proper indentation, and `terraform validate` to make sure everything is right in your code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can try to configure the Google Cloud provider like that:

```
# Configure the Google Cloud provider
provider "google" {
  credentials = "${file("${var.path_gcp_auth_json_file}")}"
  version     = "~> 2.2"
}
```

With a `variables.tf` file

```
# Path to the authentification to GCP json file 
variable "path_gcp_auth_json_file" {
  description = "Path to the authentication JSON file"
  default = "YOUR_PATH_TO_YOUR_JSON_KEY"
}
```

if you want to be quick and do not add you `default` values to a `terraform.tfvars` file.

Secondly, you missed a `{` in the end of the `tests` resource:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "tests" {
  name         = "project-tests"
  project      = "video-library-228319"
  machine_type = "f1-micro"
  zone         = "us-west1-a"

  tags = ["gcp"]

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "ubuntu-os-cloud/ubuntu-1804-lts"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "default"

    access_config {
      nat_ip = "${google_compute_address.test-static-ip-address.address}"
    }
  }
}
```

And then, to generat IPs you need to properly declare the compute resource to Terraform:

```
# Generate IPs
resource "google_compute_address" "test-static-ip-address" {
  count  = "${var.gcp_ip_count}"
  name   = "${var.gcp_project_id}-gke-ip-${count.index}"
  region = "${var.region}"
}
```

Each `"${var.[...]` need to be refered to the `variables.tf` previously mentionned.
The `count` value depends on how many IPs you need. Hope it'll help.

Comment: Hi Claire, I have edited my post as per your suggestion but I am still getting the same error, please check.